# running owncloud on https via ngix and custom port

Tags: docker, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, owncloud

I have an owncloud running behind nginx proxy to get TLS. All is running on QNap TS-251+ that already allocates HTTPS default port 443. Hence, I configured nginx via [docker-ssl-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/fsouza/docker-ssl-proxy/) to run on 8443. All is working except that owncloud sends redirects that go to default port instead of 8443 leading me to 404 errors and breaking many functions like logout, etc. I even added X-Forwarded-Port header to nginx config but owncloud does not seem to honor it.
I already spend my entire day setting all this up and have seen thousands of errors making me tired.

Is there any expert out there who has the magic hint for me? That would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Jörg

Comment: nginx is missing ProxyPassReverse that would solve my issue: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/

Comment: I found https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect and tried this but it does not work:
proxy_redirect ${TARGET_SCHEME}://${TARGET_HOST} ${TARGET_SCHEME}://${TARGET_HOST}:${SSL_PORT};

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was [proxy_redirect](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive:

```
proxy_redirect https://${TARGET_HOST} https://${TARGET_HOST}:${SSL_PORT};
```